# hibernate not working on Jboss

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, sessionfactory

I'm working on an application using Hibernate 5.0 to connect to a MySql database.
It is working fine on my environment using Tomcat V8.0.

However when I deploy the application the server which uses JBoss 6.4.0.GA
it failed when it initialize HibernateUtil.

I tried to add the Jboss-common-client as a dependency. 
Now I've got proper log but still cannot access to the database.

Do you know if I need any specific dependencies to make it work?

I have the classic:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.36</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.36</version>
</dependency>
```

And my current error on JBoss:

> JBWEB000309: type JBWEB000066: Exception report
>
> JBWEB000068: message java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not
>   initialize class com.myproject.hibernate.HibernateUtil
>
> JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000145: The server encountered an
>   internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
>
> JBWEB000070: exception
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could
>   not initialize class com.myproject.hibernate.HibernateUtil
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:420)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
>
> JBWEB000071: root cause
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   com.myproject.hibernate.HibernateUtil

and my class HibernateUtil:

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Use hibernate.cfg.xml to get a SessionFactory
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }

}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Have you upgrade Hibernate on JBoss?

Comment: I don't have any other access to JBoss except for uploading my war file. And I have no idea what you are talking about? Is it not using the library from my application? defined in the pom.xml?

Comment: No, part of it being a JavaEE Server, it comes with its own JPA implementation which happens to be a particular version of Hibernate. Which is why you can scope the Hibernate dependency as provided

Comment: So I need to either change my version of Hibernate to be the same as JBoss or upgrade hibernate on JBoss?

Comment: Ok so I have installed Jboss Dev Studio, EAP6.1+ and make the application running on it by downgrading the version of hibernate to 4.2.18.Final (found on https://access.redhat.com/articles/112673).
However it is still not working on our JBoss server and I still have the same issue.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed my issue. It was a conflict between different version of hibernate-logging (or hibernate-commons-logging).

On eclipse it was using the correct files but my jar was containing oldest version of some dependencies which were conflicting.

I fixed the issue by deleted the previous jar on my project folder.